# Can't get Saxon-CE to work

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have been trying for the past couple of days to get [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) to work locally because I want to run XSLT 2.0 transformations in the browser.

Even when I try to run the sample from [here](https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-CE/tree/master/samples) the transformation does not work and I get a blank screen.

I have the Saxonce file in the right place and have all the other files in the directory. I've tried to load the XML sample in all browsers but I still get no results and the only error I can see is in firefox i see:

> [12:49:10.939] InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable @ file:///pathtodesktop/saxonce_test/Saxonce/Saxonce.nocache.js:17

I have not made any modifications to the sample so I would assume that this should be working.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are trying to run from filestore rather than from a web server. This is possible if you set all the right security options, but I find that getting these options right is a nightmare so I never attempt it. It's much easier to set up a local web server and run your tests from there.